# Why Openshift 3 is missing from openscap static page?

Tags: openscap

I am trying to access https://static.open-scap.org/ssg-guides/ssg-ocp3-guide-index.html to understand some of the issues found in a scan but seems that this webpage is now missing. Anybody does know why?

Is there any archive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenShift 3 has been removed from upstream.  While OpenShift 3.11 will not be EOL until June 2022, the content for it will no longer be developed as OpenShift 4 content is prioritized. Starting from version 0.1.53, the OpenShift 3 guides are no longer provided. You can get the file from a previous version. The version 0.1.52 is the last version that contained OpenShift 3 content. The guides are part of the release tarball. Download and extract the release from https://github.com/ComplianceAsCode/content/releases, for example https://github.com/ComplianceAsCode/content/releases/download/v0.1.52/scap-security-guide-0.1.52.zip  and locate it in the guides directory.

Thank you very much for pointing out this problem, the http://static.open-scap.org/ page needs to be updated :)

Comment: Thank you very much!